# An error pops up when I open the second window in Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I am creating an application in which, when you click on a button in the menu section (called "command"), a second window should open for additional calculations.

I have such a problem: when I open the second window for the first time (win 2) - it works fine, but when I close it and open it again - I can't switch between input fields using the keys that I specified, although I could for the first time. Returns the following error: "_tkinter.TclError: can't invoke "focus" command: application has been destroyed".

If I open this window and open the same window again on top of it, I start switching between the input fields and these two windows.

Tell me, what could be the problem here and how to solve it? I don't have much experience, I would be very grateful for a clear answer, and help in general. Thank you.

Вот мой код:

```
from tkinter import *  
from tkinter import ttk  


def o_downKey(event):
    o_handle = event.widget.focus_get()
    o_lstHandle[(o_lstHandle.index(o_handle) + 1)%len(o_lstHandle)].focus()

def o_upKey(event):
    o_handle = event.widget.focus_get()
    o_lstHandle[(o_lstHandle.index(o_handle) - 1)%len(o_lstHandle)].focus()


def new_win():

    def win2_downKey(event):
        win2_handle = event.widget.focus_get()
        win2_lstHandle[(win2_lstHandle.index(win2_handle) + 1)%len(win2_lstHandle)].focus()

    def win2_upKey(event):
        win2_handle = event.widget.focus_get()
        win2_lstHandle[(win2_lstHandle.index(win2_handle) - 1)%len(win2_lstHandle)].focus()


    win2 = Tk()
    win2.title('Расчет квадратуры')
    win2.geometry('300x185+600+190')
    win2.resizable(0,0)

    lbl_up = Label(win2, text = 'win2 label', font = 'normal, 13')
    lbl_up.place(x=5, y=7)
    lbl_kk = Label(win2, text = 'win2 labl', font = 'normal, 13')    
    lbl_kk.place(x=5, y=34)

    ent_up = Entry(win2, font = 'noraml, 13',borderwidth=3, relief="ridge")
    win2_lstHandle.append(ent_up)
    ent_up.bind('<Left>', win2_downKey)
    ent_up.bind('<Right>', win2_upKey)
    ent_up.bind('<Return>', win2_upKey)
    ent_up.place(width=85, x=127, y=6)

    ent_kk = Entry(win2, width = 18, font = 'noraml, 13',borderwidth=3, relief="ridge")
    win2_lstHandle.append(ent_kk)
    ent_kk.bind('<Left>', win2_downKey)
    ent_kk.bind('<Right>', win2_upKey)
    ent_kk.bind('<Return>', win2_upKey)
    ent_kk.place(x=127, y=34)

    ent_up1 = Entry(win2, font = 'noraml, 13',borderwidth=3, relief="ridge")
    win2_lstHandle.append(ent_up1)
    ent_up1.bind('<Left>', win2_downKey)
    ent_up1.bind('<Right>', win2_upKey)
    ent_up1.bind('<Return>', win2_upKey)    
    ent_up1.place(width=85, x=212, y=6)


win = Tk()
win.title("CFS")  
win.geometry('500x310+500+200') 
win.resizable(0, 0)

o_lstHandle = []
win2_lstHandle = []

mainmenu = Menu(win) 
win.config(menu=mainmenu)

filemenu = Menu(mainmenu, tearoff=0)
filemenu.add_command(label="1", command = new_win)

filemenu_1 = Menu(mainmenu, tearoff=0)

filemenu_1.add_command(label="1")
filemenu_1.add_command(label="2")
filemenu_1.add_command(label="3")

mainmenu.add_cascade(label="command", menu=filemenu)
mainmenu.add_cascade(label = 'command 2', menu = filemenu_1)



frame = ttk.Frame(win, relief="groove", borderwidth = 0)
frame.pack(expand=1, fill='both')

tab_control = ttk.Notebook(frame)

tab1 = ttk.Frame(relief="groove", borderwidth = 1) 
tab3 = ttk.Frame(relief="groove", borderwidth = 1)
tab4 = ttk.Frame(relief="groove", borderwidth = 1)

s = ttk.Style()
s.configure('TNotebook.Tab', font='normal, 10')


tab_control.add(tab1, text='tab1')
tab_control.add(tab3, text='tab2')
tab_control.add(tab4, text='tab3')


tab_control.pack(expand=1, fill='both', padx=1,pady=1) 

o_ent1 = Entry(tab1, width=8, font = 'noraml, 13',borderwidth=3, relief="ridge")
o_lstHandle.append(o_ent1)
o_ent1.bind('<Down>', o_downKey)
o_ent1.bind('<Up>', o_upKey)
o_ent1.bind('<Return>', o_downKey)
o_ent1.place(x=115,y=15)

o_ent2 = Entry(tab1, width=8, font = 'noraml, 13',borderwidth=3, relief="ridge")
o_lstHandle.append(o_ent2)
o_ent2.bind('<Down>', o_downKey)
o_ent2.bind('<Up>', o_upKey)
o_ent2.bind('<Return>', o_downKey)
o_ent2.place(x=115,y=41)

o_ent3 = Entry(tab1, width=8, font = 'noraml, 13',borderwidth=3, relief="ridge")
o_lstHandle.append(o_ent3)
o_ent3.bind('<Down>', o_downKey)
o_ent3.bind('<Up>', o_upKey)
o_ent3.bind('<Return>', o_downKey)
o_ent3.place(x=115,y=67)

o_ent4 = Entry(tab1, width=8, font = 'noraml, 13',borderwidth=3, relief="ridge")
o_lstHandle.append(o_ent4)
o_ent4.bind('<Down>', o_downKey)
o_ent4.bind('<Up>', o_upKey)
o_ent4.bind('<Return>', o_downKey)
o_ent4.place(x=115,y=93) 

o_ent5 = Entry(tab1, width=8, font = 'noraml, 13',borderwidth=3, relief="ridge")
o_lstHandle.append(o_ent5)
o_ent5.bind('<Down>', o_downKey)
o_ent5.bind('<Up>', o_upKey)
o_ent5.bind('<Return>', o_downKey)
o_ent5.place(x=115,y=119)

o_ent6 = Entry(tab1, width=8, font = 'noraml, 13',borderwidth=3, relief="ridge")
o_lstHandle.append(o_ent6)
o_ent6.bind('<Down>', o_downKey)
o_ent6.bind('<Up>', o_upKey)
o_ent6.bind('<Return>', o_downKey)
o_ent6.place(x=115,y=145)


o_lb1 = Label(tab1, text='label 1', font = 'noraml, 13')
o_lb1.place(x=15,y=15)

o_lb2 = Label(tab1, text='label 2', font = 'noraml, 13')
o_lb2.place(x=15,y=41)

o_lb3 = Label(tab1, text='label 3', font = 'noraml, 13')
o_lb3.place(x=15,y=67)

o_lb4 = Label(tab1, text='label 4', font = 'noraml, 13')
o_lb4.place(x=15,y=93)

o_lb5 = Label(tab1, text='label 5', font = 'noraml, 13')
o_lb5.place(x=15,y=119)

o_lb6 = Label(tab1, text='label 6', font = 'noraml, 13')
o_lb6.place(x=15,y=145)


otkr_knop = Button(tab1, text = 'Button 1', font = 'noraml, 13', borderwidth=3, relief="ridge")
otkr_knop.place(x=10,y=230)

o_ochist = Button(tab1, text = 'Button 2', font = 'noraml, 13', borderwidth=3, relief="ridge")
o_ochist.place(x=110,y=230)


canvas = Canvas(tab1, bg="white", width=280, height=258,   relief=GROOVE, bd=3)
canvas.pack(anchor = SE)

tpk1 = Label(tab1, text = 'text"', font  = 'Arial 9 bold roman', fg='blue')
tpk1.place(x=402,y=264)

mytex = canvas.create_text(150, 135, text="")


win.mainloop()
```

Comment: Creating more than one instance of `Tk` usually causes more problems than it solves. Is there a specific reason you're doing that instead of using `Toplevel` for all windows except the root window?

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem on my machine...

Comment: The situation with `Toplevel`  is exactly the same

Comment: It is because you have used same global variable `win2_lstHandle` to store the references of those `Entry` widgets in the new window created. The calculation of the *next* widget to be focused works when first window created.  However after the first window is destroyed and second new window is created, the size of `win2_lstHandle` will be 6 instead of 3, so the calculation of the next widget to be focused is wrong and point to the destroyed `Entry` widget in the first window.  You can use an attribute of the new window instead of global variable.

Comment: @acw1668 Can you demonstrate how this can be done ?

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because you have used same global variable `win2_lstHandle` to store the references of those `Entry` widgets in the new window created. The calculation of the *next widget* to be focused works when first window is created. However after the first window is destroyed and second new window is created, the size of `win2_lstHandle` will be 6 instead of 3, so the calculation of the *next widget* to be focused is wrong and point to the destroyed `Entry` widget in the first window.

You can use an *attribute* of the new window instead of global variable.  Below is the modified `new_win()` using an attribute instead of global variable to store the entry widgets:

```py
def new_win():

    def win2_downKey(event):
        win2_handle = event.widget.focus_get()
        win2.lstHandle[(win2.lstHandle.index(win2_handle) + 1)%len(win2.lstHandle)].focus()

    def win2_upKey(event):
        win2_handle = event.widget.focus_get()
        win2.lstHandle[(win2.lstHandle.index(win2_handle) - 1)%len(win2.lstHandle)].focus()

    # better use Toplevel() instead of Tk() for child window
    win2 = Toplevel()
    win2.title('Расчет квадратуры')
    win2.geometry('300x185+600+190')
    win2.resizable(0,0)

    lbl_up = Label(win2, text = 'win2 label', font = 'normal, 13')
    lbl_up.place(x=5, y=7)
    lbl_kk = Label(win2, text = 'win2 labl', font = 'normal, 13')
    lbl_kk.place(x=5, y=34)

    win2.lstHandle = []  # use an attribute to store the references of entry widgets

    ent_up = Entry(win2, font = 'noraml, 13',borderwidth=3, relief="ridge")
    win2.lstHandle.append(ent_up)
    ent_up.bind('<Left>', win2_downKey)
    ent_up.bind('<Right>', win2_upKey)
    ent_up.bind('<Return>', win2_upKey)
    ent_up.place(width=85, x=127, y=6)

    ent_kk = Entry(win2, width = 18, font = 'noraml, 13',borderwidth=3, relief="ridge", bg="gold")
    win2.lstHandle.append(ent_kk)
    ent_kk.bind('<Left>', win2_downKey)
    ent_kk.bind('<Right>', win2_upKey)
    ent_kk.bind('<Return>', win2_upKey)
    ent_kk.place(x=127, y=34)

    ent_up1 = Entry(win2, font = 'noraml, 13',borderwidth=3, relief="ridge")
    win2.lstHandle.append(ent_up1)
    ent_up1.bind('<Left>', win2_downKey)
    ent_up1.bind('<Right>', win2_upKey)
    ent_up1.bind('<Return>', win2_upKey)
    ent_up1.place(width=85, x=212, y=6)
```

---

Or simply use a local variable instead:

```py
def new_win():
    # create a local variable
    win2_lstHandle = []

    ...
```

Comment: Thank you very much!! You, with your really useful and detailed answers, help me out for the second time

Comment: @shbidibom If it solves your issue, upvote and accept it as the answer to show your appreciation.